# Count first 12 values in a column (Google Sheets/Scripts)

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering whether there was a formula/script I could construct in order to count the first 12 values in a column of numbers. I have a series of clients who have started working with my company at different times but I want to determine how the clients perform within the first 12 months of being with us.

As some clients have been with us for 14 months and others for 3 years, I always need to calculate an average from the first 12 values in a column. Ideally I wanted a formula/script that would check a column (let's say 'column A') look down until the bottom is reached (a blank cell- this signals when the client joined) and then count 12 cells up from there to get the first year's worth of data.

Is this possible? I'm thinking this is Google Script territory. I am okay (but not fantastic) at writing Javascript so if this is the avenue I have to go down, I will hopefully be able to follow.

[image]

Comment: This could be done by using built-in functions. It's not clear if the first values are at the top of the column or at the bottom.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. How about SHOWING what you mean?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry. Here is an image of what I mean. Each individual sheet has a different client and the column I have shown is simply the number of visitors for that client for that particular month. I have highlighted the bottom 12 cells on the sheet (technically the first 12 months the client was with us).

As you'll be able to see, as each client has been with us for different amounts of time, the first 12 months are never in the came location in the sheet (e.g. client 1 range is A16:A27 whereas Client 2 is A13:A24)

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=21lr96e&s=8#.VXfxwlVVhBc

Comment: Rather than add relevant content as a comment, you should edit your answer to improve its quality.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

There's no need of using a script as the desired result could be got by using built-in formulas and their performance is better for this case as it looks to have a small number of formulas and values.

- Use `=COUNT(OFFSET(A$3,MAX(0,COUNT(A$3:A)-12),0,12,1))` to count the last 12 numeric values in the column A.
- Use `=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A$3,MAX(0,COUNT(A$3:A)-12),0,12,1))` to get the average of the last 12 values in column A.

## Explanation

The OP is referring to the values in a chronological order were the most recent entered values are at the top and the oldest ("firsts") at the bottom.

It's assumed that the columns use the first two rows as headers, and there aren't values below the "first" value for the corresponding client.

The following formula will return the bottom 12 values in a column, ignoring the first two rows. If the column has less that 12 values, it will return the first 12 cells in the column. It could be used as parameter of COUNT(), AVERAGE() and other functions.

```
OFFSET(A$3,MAX(0,COUNT(A$3:A)-12),0,12,1)
```

### References

- [COUNT - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620?hl=en)
- [AVERAGE - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615?hl=es)
- [OFFSET - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=es)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you have misunderstood my original question (or I'm not very good at explaining!). I can't use the =COUNT(RANGE) formula because each column will have a different number of values in it.

For example;

=COUNT(A1:12) could be the first 12 values for one column but the last 12 values in a different column (as there are more values for the different column).